# Add items on array using loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I want to add item to my array using loop. But i can't make it right.

I tried this code, and it can't gave me the Format/Output i want.

```
$img_arr[]= "";
foreach ($images as $image) { 
    $img_arr['src'][] .=  $image['src'];
}
```

i want this kind of output.

```
array (
    'src' => 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/3.jpg',
  ),
  array (
    'src' => 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/2-1.jpg',
  ),
  array (
    'src' => 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/3.jpg',
  ),
  array (
    'src' => 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/1-1.jpg',
  ),
  array (
    'src' => 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/4-1.jpg',
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you code a bit:

```
$img_arr = []; //create an array variable
foreach ($images as $image) {
  //assign child-array to newly create array variable
  $img_arr[] =  ['src'=>$image['src']]; 
}
print_r($img_arr); //check desired output coming or not?
```

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
foreach ($images as $image) { 
    $img_arr['src'][] .=  $image['src'];
}
```

adds a single array to $img_arr, with "src" as the key, and the URLs as the values. The period before the equals sign is also unnecessary.

You want this:

```
foreach ($images as $image) { 
    $img_arr[] =  ['src' => $image['src']];
}
```

This adds a series of new arrays to $img_arr. Each array added is a key value pair, key = "src", value = [whatever the URL is].

Answer (score 0):

```
$images = [
    ['src'=>'1.jpg'],
    ['src'=>'2.jpg'],
    ['src'=>'3.jpg'],
    ['src'=>'4.jpg'],
    ['src'=>'5.jpg'],
    ['src'=>'6.jpg']
];

$url = 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/';
$img_arr = array();
foreach($images as $image){
    $img_arr[] = ['src' => $url.$image['src']];
}

print_r($img_arr);

Output:  
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [src] => https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/1.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [src] => https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/2.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [src] => https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/3.jpg
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [src] => https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/4.jpg
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [src] => https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/5.jpg
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [src] => https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/6.jpg
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize the array with `$img_arr[] = "";` which will result in

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

I think you meant `$img_arr = [];`

In the foreach you use `.=` which is a string [concatenation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) operator. You can omit the dot and use just `[]` to push an element to the end of the array.

Then adding to `src` as the key in the foreach will give you an array with 2 keys where the first is 0 and is unused the the second is `key`.

An alternative could be using [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$img_arr = array_map(function ($x) {
    return ['src' => $x["src"]];
}, $images);

print_r($img_arr);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [src] => https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/3.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [src] => https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/2-1.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [src] => https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/3.jpg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [src] => https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/1-1.jpg
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [src] => https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/4-1.jpg
        )

)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/WtJJY)